# How to show all category and their subcategory in menu in magento2

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation, magento-2.0.2

I want to show all category in the menu and on the mouse-over their subcategories will be shown. Right now it is showing only one subcategory in menu. No category and subcategory are showing inside menu.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have selected **Yes** for **Is Active** and **Include in Navigation Menu** or not.

Also if you want to show in left menu, then value of **Is Anchor** should also be **Yes**.

**Note:** After saving, remove cache, page_cache and reindex.

Comment: Enable category is Yes and included in menu is yes. Is there any other thing that i need to enable to show the category in menu

Comment: Please check what is value of **Maximal Depth** under **Stores >> Configuration >> Catalog (Catalog) >> Category Top Navigation**? It should be 0.

Comment: I have make the value to 0 but still i am not getting category in menu

Comment: Have you cleared all types of cache and reindexed data also?

Comment: I have cleared all the cache and reindexed data also but still I am not getting the category in menu

Comment: Are you using magento's default theme or any other custom theme?

Comment: I am using fasony theme of magento. When i Was using their default theme at that time also i was not getting the categories  in the menu so i don't think that this problem occur due to change in theme.

Comment: Could you please give some more specification of your issue like screenshot and what you do with categories?